# Como executar arquivo PHP a partir de função em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Tenho a seguinte estrutura para registro de uma nova conta em banco de dados MySQL (register.php):

```
<?php  
  $con = mysqli_connect("meu_host","meu_user","minha_senha","banco");
  mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO contas VALUES (" + $id + ", " + $pass + ", '" + $dat + "', '" + $email + "')");
  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Tenho os seguintes elementos na minha página:

```
<input type="text" id="ident" />
<input type="password" id="pass" />
<input type="email" id="em" />
<input type="button" onclick="register();" value="Register" name="Reg" />
```

E o seguinte *script* embutido no `header` da página:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function register(){
    dat = new Date();
    id = document.getElementById('ident').value;
    pass = document.getElementById('pass').value;
    em = document.getElementById('em').value;
    <!-- alert("<?PHP register(id,pass,dat,em); ?>"); -->
  }
</script>
```

E minha questão, qual é a melhor e mais rápida convenção para executar o arquivo PHP a partir de uma função em Javascript? 
O comado comentado me foi passado por um colega, mas não funcionou.

Nota: a conexão com o banco de dados está funcionando perfeitamente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para um javascript executar um .php é necessario utilizar ajax nesse exemplo é necessario adicionar a biblioteca [jquery](http://jquery.com/) para funcionar corretamente.

Esse código não funciona pq o php é processado primeiro e depois o javascript. Os argumentos são passados em branco pois o js só vai funcionar quando a página for renderizada.

```
alert("<?PHP register(id,pass,dat,em); ?>");
```

//form.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function gravar(){
        
        $.ajax({
            method: "post",
            url: "gravar.php",
            data: $("#form").serialize(),
        success: function(data){
                   alert(data);
        }
        
    });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form" action="" onsubmit="gravar(); return false;">
  id: <input type="text" id="ident" name="id" />
  pass: <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" />
  email:<input type="email" id="em" name="email"/>
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Utilize *preparestatements*, isso deixa seu código mais seguro e menos vulneravel a sql injection

gravar.php

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO contas VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

$id = $_POST['id'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$data = date('Y-m-d');
$email = $_POST['email'];


$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "isss", $id, $pass, $data, $email);
if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
     echo 'registros inserido com sucesso';
}else{
     echo mysqli_error($con);
}
```

recomendo uma lida em [mysqli_stmt_bind_param()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: Como poderia postar a data atual do sistema ao invés de uma definida no *form*?

Comment: `+1` - seria interessante colocar um exemplo com vanilla uma vez que a pergunta não têm tag jQuery

Comment: Fiz exatamente como na resposta, e o registro não foi inserido. Uma vez que a página é atualizada, eu não consigo ver os resultados dos *echos* para *debug*. Ideia?

Comment: @Guill, se utiliza o firefox instale uma debugger de javascript como o firebug para ver o retorno do ajax. No alert não aparece nada?

Comment: @perdeu Uso o Chrome. Não aparece nada. Apenas atualiza a página e mostra os valores do form na url, inclusive a senha... Um detalhe: no banco de dados o meu campo password é do tipo inteiro, então substituí "isss" por "iiss". Fiz correto?

Comment: Aperte F12 no chrome, e execute o código novamente, veja se vai aparecer algum erro no console.

Comment: "GET http://giproductions.byethost24.com/jquery-1.10.1.js 404 (Not Found)"  Parece que eu preciso importar a lib jQuery para o servidor FTP.

Comment: Importei a jQuery e funcionou. Como a *tag* jQuery não faz parte da pergunta, peço que deixe por escrito na resposta, que é preciso ter o arquivo "jquery-1.10.1.js" na pasta da página.