# Executar função php com onclick

Tags: php, html, onclick

Quero saber como posso executar uma função php com o evento onclick em um elemento `a`, tendo como exemplo:

```
<a href="">Teste onclick</a>
```

E a função:

```
function testeOnclick() {

echo 'Bem vindo ao SOpt';

}
```

Comment: Use ajax amigo.

Comment: possível duplicata de [Como executar arquivo PHP a partir de função em JavaScript?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10424/como-executar-arquivo-php-a-partir-de-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-em-javascript)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento A pergunta realmente é parecida, mas não acho que seja a ponto de ser fechada como duplicata. Tendo em vista que  minha pergunta está mais direta (assim como já tem respostas bem objetivas também) e poderia ajudar tanto novos usuários como alguém que tenha um conhecimento menor no assunto, e que consegui resolver meu problema com as respostas daqui, e não com a de lá.

Comment: @GWER A duplicata não invalida a sua pergunta, apenas vincula ambas perguntas, eu pessoalmente acho que a resposta do rray resolveria sim o seu problema. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você terá que usar Ajax. Supondo que o arquivo php que contém a sua função se chame "meuajax.php", usando jQuery, pode usar:

```
function chamarPhpAjax() {
   $.ajax({
      url:'meuajax.php',
      complete: function (response) {
         alert(response.responseText);
      },
      error: function () {
          alert('Erro');
      }
  });  

  return false;
}
```

Então no seu link:

```
 <a href="" onclick="return chamarPhpAjax();">Teste onclick</a>
```

O seu arquivo "meuajax.php":

```
function testeOnclick() {
    echo 'Bem vindo ao SOpt';
}

testeOnclick();
```

Answer (score 6):

O que pode fazer é isso:

```
<a href="pagina.php?id=1">Teste onclick</a>
```

Ai em PHP faça assim:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['id']) == 1){

 testeOnclick();
}

?>
```

Seria uma forma simples de se fazer, mas pesquise sobre Json/Ajax com PHP faz isso mas de uma forma que não precisa atualizar a página.

Comment: Valeu pela resposta, realmente é uma maneira BEM mais simples de fazer, pena que atualiza a página! De qualquer forma obrigado. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Se possível, você deve criar a rotina em JavaScript, mas se não tiver outro jeito, você deverá executar a função PHP de duas formas:

**a)** Criando um arquivo PHP que rode a função, e quando a pessoa clicar, redirecionar para o arquivo que executa a ação e faz o que tem de ser feito a seguir.

**b)** Criar um arquivo PHP que chama funções utilizando o método call_user_func e fazer uma requisição ajax para acessar o mesmo, como no exemplo a seguir:

**Código JavaScript** (jQuery):

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e){
    $.post('execute.php', {fuction: 'helloWorld'}, function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

Código PHP:

```
<?php
// execute.php

function helloWorld(){
   echo 'Olá Stackoverflow! :)';
}

call_user_func($_POST['function']);
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!