# Executar um if no php somente após um clique no botão

Tags: php, javascript

Preciso executar um *if* no PHP somente se houver um *click* no botão.
Não havendo um *click* o *if* não executa. Já imagino que vou precisar interagir o JavaScript com PHP, mas... Li diversos posts mas ainda não consegui fazer.

Simplificando, seria algo como isso:

```
<a href="">Clique</a>

<?php 

if (Clique == true) {
    Execute isso;
}else{
    Não execute nada;
}
```

Comment: A questão é: e o resto do *script*? Ele deve ser executado quando? Onde está esse código PHP? No mesmo arquivo que o botão? O que esse *if* irá fazer? Tem como [edit] a pergunta descrevendo tudo isso? Aliás, se é novo aqui, recomendo que faças o [tour] pelo site.

Comment: Possível [duplicada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66451/executar-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-php-com-onclick).

Comment: basta você utilizar a função onclick

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você quis dizer que **ao clicar em um botão especifico** realizar algo que está dentro do if em PHP.

Basta passar um parâmetro no URL do **botão especifico** e fazer a verificação.

```
<a href="url_pagina_destino?p=execute">Botão especifico</a>

<a href="url_pagina_destino">Botão qualquer</a>

<?php 

    if ($_GET['p'] == "execute") {
        echo "Executei isso";
    }else{
        //Não executei nada;
    }

?>
```