# Session passando valor que não era esperado

Tags: php, javascript, html, session

Olá, sou um programador e estou fazendo um sistema para a escola que eu estudei, mas encontrei um grande problema.

Sistema Escolar

```
<h1 id="titulo">Sistema Escolar</h1>

    <div>
        <ul id="menu">
            <a href="inicio2.html"><li>Página inicial</li></a>
            <li>Informativos</li>
            <li>Bio dos Educadores</li>
            <li>Cursos</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<div id="lateral">

    <img src="imagens/BrasaoDoCearaPeq.png"/>
    <h4>EEEP SALOMÃO ALVES DE MOURA</h4>

    <h2>Ranking das Salas</h2>
    <ol id="ranking">
        <li>Informática</li>
        <li>Redes</li>
        <li>Edificações</li>
        <li>Comércio</li>
        <li>Secretariado</li>
    </ol>

</div>

<div id="corpo">
    <h1>Selecione o curso desejado</h1>

    <div id="primeiroAno">
        <h3>1º Ano</h3>         
        <ul>    
            <a href="cadAluno.html"><li class="informatica" onclick="<?php $_SESSION['selctcurso'] = 'informatica1'; ?>"><img src="imagens/icones/informatica.png"><br/>Informática</li></a>
            <a href="cadAluno.html"><li class="edificacoes" onclick="<?php $_SESSION['selctcurso'] = 'edificacoes1'; ?>"><img src="imagens/icones/edificacoes.png"/><br/>Edificações</li></a>
            <a href="cadAluno.html"><li class="redes" onclick="<?php $_SESSION['selctcurso'] = 'redes1'; ?>"><img src="imagens/icones/redes.png"/><br/>Redes</li></a>
            <a href="cadAluno.html"><li class="logistica" onclick="<?php $_SESSION['selctcurso'] = 'logistica1'; ?>"><img src="imagens/icones/logistica.png"/><br/>Logística</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="segundoAno">
        <h3>2º Ano</h3>
        <ul>
            <a href="cadAluno.html"><li class="informatica" onclick="<?php $_SESSION['selctcurso'] = 'informatica2'; ?>"><img src="imagens/icones/informatica.png"><br/>Informática</li></a>
            <a href="cadAluno.html"><li class="comercio" onclick="<?php $_SESSION['selctcurso'] = 'comercio2'; ?>"><img src="imagens/icones/comercio.png"/><br/>Comércio</li></a>
            <a href="cadAluno.html"><li class="redes" onclick="<?php $_SESSION['selctcurso'] = 'redes2'; ?>"><img src="imagens/icones/redes.png"/><br/>Redes</li></a>
            <a href="cadAluno.html"><li class="logistica" onclick="<?php $_SESSION['selctcurso'] = 'logistica2'; ?>"><img src="imagens/icones/logistica.png"/><br/>Logística</li>
        </ul></a>
    </div>

    <div id="terceiroAno">
        <h3>3º Ano</h3>
        <ul>
            <a href="cadAluno.html"><li class="edificacoes" onclick="<?php $_SESSION['selctcurso'] = 'edificações3'; ?>"><img src="imagens/icones/edificacoes.png"><br/>Edificações</li></a>
            <a href="cadAluno.html"><li class="comercio" onclick="<?php $_SESSION['selctcurso'] = 'comercio3'; ?>"><img src="imagens/icones/comercio.png"/><br/>Comércio</li></a>
            <a href="cadAluno.html"><li class="redes" onclick="<?php $_SESSION['selctcurso'] = 'redes3'; ?>"><img src="imagens/icones/redes.png"/><br/>Redes</li></a>
            <a href="cadAluno.html"><li class="secretariado" onclick="<?php $_SESSION['selctcurso'] = 'secretariado3'; ?>"><img src="imagens/icones/secretariado.png"/><br/>Secretariado</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Esse é o codigo do arquivo escolhacurso.php o problema é quando o professor vai cadastrar um aluno ele tem que passar nessa tela para selecionar o curso quando efetua o cadastro sempre o curso é salvo no banco de dados como secretariado 3 que é o ultimo curso, mas não é para acontecer isso, ele tem que clicar num curso e no curso que ele clicou é para ser salvo junto com o aluno. Algum programador php mais experiente poderia me ajudar ??
Desde já eu agradeço a ajuda de todos

Comment: Relacionadas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10424/como-executar-arquivo-php-a-partir-de-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-javascript, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/36709/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-rodar-uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-javascript-pelo-php

Comment: Morpheus, PHP não roda paralelamente com o HTML e JavaScript, o que o PHP faz é processar no servidor e devolver o download de um HTML que é posteriormente renderizado e executado pelo servidor, isso é como ocorre o processo do HTTP com o cliente (navegador), web é isso HTTP, HTML só se comunicaria com PHP diretamente se fosse o *DeLorean*... Então a única abordagem que irá funcionar no seu caso é Ajax... Coloquei alguns links no topo de sua pergunta, existem vários exemplos de abordagens que você pode experimentar.

Comment: vlw cara, você me ajudou muito, vou dar uma olhada em como funciona o ajax pra tentar resolver esse problema.

Answer (score 2):

O código não tem sentido uma vez que o [PHP vai executar tudo e enviar para o cliente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/36709/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-rodar-uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-javascript-pelo-php).

Quando você faz:

```
<li class="secretariado" onclick="<?php $_SESSION['selctcurso'] = 'secretariado3'; ?>">
```

É o mesmo que fazer:

```
QualquerCoisa<?php $_SESSION['selctcurso'] = 'secretariado3'; ?>TalvezOutraCoisa
```

O PHP não vai entender nada do HTML, ele não sabe nem sequer que isso existe. O `onclick=` é o mesmo que o Javascript `.addEventListener("click", ...)`, isso só vai ser executado no cliente, porém o PHP (o `$_SESSION['selctcurso']`) é executado antes, no seu servidor.

---

É mais do que lógico que, em situações normais, se você está definindo N * `$_SESSION['selctcurso']`, apenas o último é o que vai se manter.

---

Se você quer que ao clicar seja definido um valor para sessão, você pode simplesmente fazer uma nova requisição. Nesta página requisitada você define a sessão.

Comment: vlw pela resposta, mas não ajudou tanto seu você pudesse me mostrar uma dica de como eu poderia fazer isso eu agradeceria.